# Why can I not use the Make Segments command on my Surface NURBS Curves?

Tags: modeling, nurbs-surface

I followed the tutorial on the [Modeling/Surfaces/Skinning wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Tutorials/Modeling/Surfaces/Skinning), and then I created a simple test. I created a Surface NURBS curve, made 3 copies with space between them, selected all, and hit <kbd>F</kbd>, but nothing happened. No error or any indication that <kbd>F</kbd> is supposed to do anything was displayed. I am new to Blender and am using version 2.70, so not sure what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem?

Comment: If the answer below solved your problem, don't forget to click the ["Solved" checkmark](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yQeQQ8ImENMnU1ZmpBYjI4WlE/edit?usp=sharing) to let everyone know the question has been solved. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After reading the tutorial, here are a few points you can check in your workflow:

### Point #1

Make sure you add a ***Surface*** NURB Curve, not any other kind of object. A "[Surface](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Surfaces)" is different from a "[Mesh](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes)" or a "[Curve](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Curves)", as you can see here in the Add menu:

[image]

Notice there are other objects that have NURB or Curve in their name, but these are **not** what the tutorial is describing:

[image]

So, when adding a new object, go by the first level of names, as shown here:

[image]

### Point #2

After Adding the first Surface NURB Curve, you must be in Edit mode when you duplicate it
(<kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>), because the [Make Segments](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Curves/Editing) command (<kbd>F</kbd>) will **only** work in Edit mode.

[image]

If you were **not** in Edit mode when you made the duplicates, each one would be it's own separate object and the <kbd>F</kbd> command would not work.

By duplicating the surfaces while in Edit mode, all of the duplicates are considered one object,
**even if they are not connected** (which they aren't until you use <kbd>F</kbd>)

### Point #3

After duplicating the Surfaces, stay in Edit mode, then select All with <kbd>A</kbd>, and then press <kbd>F</kbd> to Make Segments (connect them all together):

[image]

Just to explain the name of the command, when you use "Make Segments" (<kbd>F</kbd>), the "segments" that are made are the ones connecting the vertices together, shown here in yellow on the right:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try when I get home later.  But I see I was not doing point #2 or #3, as I didn't get that I needed to be in edit mode.