# Create a surface within bounding curves?

Tags: bezier-curves

EDIT: My example was misleading. I don't want to use polys/faces. Please see the example of how this is done in Maya:

[image]

My first example didn't make it clear that I want to influence the way the "bridge" is formed by the other bounding curves. Is there not a way to do this? Curves can be used to define a bevel (which creates a surface) but it seems there is not a way to model like this. Please let me know if you know of a way to model like this using surfaces or something other than polygon faces. Thanks!

Original:
I am trying to make a car using curves. How do I create an interpolated surface between them? (How to I patch them together?)
Here's a simple example. I have these two curves:
[image: Two curves to be interpolated to create a surface between them.]

Here's a mockup of what I mean:
[image: Mockup of patched curves.]

I've done this in Maya, and here's the [user-guide page on how to do exactly this. (click here)](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/en_us/index.html?url=files/Creating_NURBS_surfaces_Create_a_surface_within_bounding_curves.htm,topicNumber=d30e176911) There has to be a way to do this in Blender. I just have to believe! ;)
Thanks for your help!
-Ben

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28101/1853

Comment: A curve and a surface are actually two different object types. You can't add a surface to a curve only object. As mentioned in other answers you can convert your curve to a mesh and add faces to it. If you want to do your modelling with a surface object, you will need to add a new surface object and start again.

Comment: You can create [some shapes](http://i.imgur.com/MjkPX1k.jpg) using [surfaces](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/surfaces/introduction.html). However, if the curve exhists already I think you can use it only as a reference.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/how-to-make-uv-loft-like-3ds-max-in-blender-using-curves

Answer (score 7):

Add a *Curve* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>*-->Curve-->Bezier*) and model the first profile being in *Edit Mode*. When finished, select it (<kbd>A</kbd>), duplicate (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and place as far from the first one as you want. Model the duplicated second profile as you like.
[image]

Go to *Object Mode*, change the curve's resolution (*Preview U* and *Render U*) to 3, then select it and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>*-->Convert to Mesh*.
[image]

Go to *User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) and enable the ***F2 add-on***.
[image]

Select two vertices as pictured below and press <kbd>F</kbd> continuously to fill the gaps.
[image]

Add a ***Subsurf Modifier*** to the mesh to make it look smoother. Enable a *Smooth Shading* in the *Edit* panel of a ***Tool Shelf*** (<kbd>T</kbd>).
[image]
[image]

Comment: As pdlarry suggested, Brige Edge Loops operation works better and faster than F2 add-on. And you have some extra options when you use it: http://www.gfycat.com/WetEmbarrassedIlladopsis

Comment: I edited my original post to clarify my question. I am wanting to know how to model without polys/faces, just using curves. Much like you can create two curves and use one as the bevel object of the other (creating a "surface") I wonder if there is a way to make other surfaces out of curves that I can control and model with aside from just bevels. I've noticed the "NURBS" surface option, but I can't control NURBS the same way.

Comment: @Ben Mora, please see this related answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/how-to-make-uv-loft-like-3ds-max-in-blender-using-curves It may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for this!! This got me out of my banner creating jam!

Answer (score 5):

If the two curves have the same number of vertices, you could, in Edit Mode, select both curves and then Mesh->Edges->Bridge Edge Loops.

Comment: bridge edge loops will only work with a mesh not with curves.

Comment: True. Convert curves to meshes first, as Gonzou suggested.