# Blender sverchok lofting with array of boxes

Tags: modeling, modifiers, node-editor, sverchok

I found this threat "[How do you loft between curves?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28072/how-do-you-loft-between-curves)" and i used that specific combination of nodes to achieve lofting between curves.

But instead of simply plate, I would like to use array of thin boxes (like wooden planks). How can I archive that?

Edit 5.2.2017:

[image]

Here is an example. So the selected curves presents the control curves and the grid presents the interpolation between them. And this interpolation should define the path and the curvature of those arrayed boxes. All dimensions (X,Y,Z) should be usable.

Comment: Does the solution have to depend specifically on the Sverchok add-on? And should the outer contour of the boxes follow the outside contour of the loft (i.e. similar to lattice) or should it stay “rectangular” (e.g. like shrinkwrap)?

Comment: Yes, outer contour of the boxes should follow the outside contour of the loft. Shrink Wrap is option as long as curves doesn't turn around it's own axes. Because Shrink Warp is always projection from one axis (from x for example). 
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach this differently,

- First create the curved surface by lofting,
- Use modulo to make a masklist to discard the faces that represent the space in-between the planks
- Then finally extrude the faces using the *Solidify* node (via the Normal to turn the faces into "plank" geometry.

use the SV Import / Export panel to import this gist:
https://gist.github.com/2bda764a9f6aa7e9a6aca69d7181bdaa

[image]

here the usage of Solidy Node and Delete Loose (the "rest" verts that aren't used)

[image]

as a gist: https://gist.github.com/0216592fedb22856d4f3778e4187cec0

Comment: By the way, what is the best way of updating the node tree?
I have to always drop and get curves again to see update.

Comment: @Daniel, it should update automatically if you have the timeline playing, or simply change frame. There's also an option hidden away in Sverchok's preferences to show a "Live Update" toggle in Sverchok's 3dview tab. Might be worth a new question if this wasn't enough detail.

Answer (score 2):

please, use sverchok join vertices from interpolation to matrix viewer draw (or bmesh viewer or mesh instancer nodes) and to data - your object to multiply
this is gits to import to sverchok:
https://gist.github.com/3d3d6211602be78e1d82b36492a90372
copy number 3d3d6211602be78e1d82b36492a90372
and import from clipboard (no need paste)
[image]

Comment: The answer is hard to understand in its current state. Please edit the question and make what you are saying clearer and easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Zeriffi for your answer! Your idea is clever and I will use it!

I found another option by using StripesMULT node (put StripesMULT's Attractor values high enough to avoid differences between planks).

But this method causes some odd stretching and planks won´t remain straight.

[image]