# Non destructive curve to mesh ?

Tags: bezier-curves

i want to join all thoses curves with faces in a non destructive way , to form an organic building.
so when i join them with faces i want to still have the possibility to ajust thoses curves.

is it possible to do that ?

[image]

Comment: even if you convert them to mesh you could transform and animate with Shapekeys

Comment: Relevant: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28101/16395 (sverchok add-on solution)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible when **Surface**> NURBS Curves or NURBS Circles are used. Add and select them all and join with Ctrl+J in Object Mode. Next go to Edit Mode and press A followed by F. In edit mode you can stretch your shape to the endpoints and edit it. Once done,you may use Alt+C to convert object to mesh. NB: the number of control points must be **the same** for each element.

Comment: i know about nurb , unfortunatly thoses are not supported by boolean for example , and this is a big no for a lot of people

also the form created dont pass trough the actual line of the curve , it just created a vague approximation of it ...

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Add Surface -> **Nurbs circle**

[image]

Add few Circles with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> Duplicating

Select the circles and Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to Join

In Edit mode Select All and Press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the Faces.

Now with the curves verts u can control the shape.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IowF.jpg

Comment: i know about nurb , unfortunatly thoses are not supported by boolean for example , and this is a big no for a lot of people

also the form created dont pass trough the actual line of the curve , it just created a vague approximation of it ...