# Techniques for forming curved surface?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

[image]In the above picture, I need to form a curved surface in the holes between the rim of the faces, and the two vertex curves above the hole. The surface is quite complex, curving across all three axis - following the arrows I've annotated (These are exaggerated arrows).

I had formed the initial two curves from beziers, which worked great - but I can't figure out how to replicate the same angle of the first two curves across a grid of beziers (because the handle system makes it imprecise, and the beziers need to scale smaller as they follow the x-axis rim).

My main question is - how can I create this surface? Any tips would be appreciated.

---

EDIT: This is NOT a duplicate. The articles linked by Duarte Farrjota Ramos are unhelpful because:

A) - I'm not working with beziers, paths or splines (As am limited by the mesh of the object).

B) - Lofting doesn't work properly between 3 seperate curves, and you cannot control the grid generated (which means it is distorted and intersects itself).

C) Similarly Grid Fill is haphazard for producing artefacts and distortions. It ALMOST works - but invariably includes artefacts and bumps

C) Bridging only works between two curves - not 3 (To the same effct as lofting).

D) - The Curve Tools addon is outdated - and was outdated in the 2015 article linked. It lacks the functionality to do this.

Hence, the question still stands as far as I'm concerned...

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28072/how-do-you-loft-between-curves https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/746/lofting-between-splines

Comment: Unfortunately, with blender you're only going to be able to use the spline/curve techniques and then convert to mesh.  I'll vote to reopen, because the other answers don't deal with melding the results of spline modeling to an existing mesh, but I don't think other people will agree with me.

Comment: @Marty Fouts - That's a far more helpful/constructive answer than simply closing it down and pointing to posts that don't actually address this particular issue. 

Should it be an impossible task to merge the two (As per my OP), I guess an option would be to create a new bezier matching each annotated curve, loft/bridge/grid fill between them and then try to rework them into the original object. But that's an extra layer of work I was hoping to avoid. Thanks for the advice.