# Q Automated surface generation?

Tags: python, nurbs-surface

I have a NURBS surface definitions (i.e. the control node positions) but want to automate the generation of the surface in Blender.

Currently I generate a flat regular grid of control nodes by staring with a flat surface and repeatedly using

`bpy.ops.curve.extrude_move(TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0,1,0)})`

or

`bpy.ops.curve.extrude_move(TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(1,0,0)})`

I can then select each control point in turn and using for example

`bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-3.52127,-3.49763,2.31155))`

move it to where I want it to be.

I can generate these lines automatically (Mathcad & Excel) but do not know how to shift between control points automatically, or access and define the locations directly without using the GUI.

Can someone propse a Python script to either cycle through the rows and columns defining the locations or select the next point in the U or V curve?

Comment: [This answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8593/34236) provides a script that generates a NURBS surface. Maybe you could try to tweak it to match your UV shape.