# How to make a curve path from scratch given a list of (x, y, z) points?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, path, soft-body

I want to move a soft body object in my scene on a path (curve path). For the path, I want to make it myself from scratch. I basically have a Python List containing (x, y, z) points and want to create a curve path from scratch given these points using a Python script. However, it looks like the way the vertices are stored for *paths* is different than meshes as I cannot find something like `nurbsPathObj.data.vertices`. So I wonder, how can I manually add new vertices to a path or remove some of them via Blender's Python API?

Comment: What kind of path? Do you mean a curve?

Comment: @brockmann Edited the question. I think it should be more clear now

Comment: Take a look on this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6750/poly-bezier-curve-from-a-list-of-coordinates

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe something like this?
See also: [Create NURBS surface with Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7020/create-nurbs-surface-with-python#8593)

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

coords_list = [[0,1,2], [1,2,3], [-3,2,1], [0,0,-4]]

# make a new curve
crv = bpy.data.curves.new('crv', 'CURVE')
crv.dimensions = '3D'

# make a new spline in that curve
spline = crv.splines.new(type='NURBS')

# a spline point for each point
spline.points.add(len(coords_list)-1) # theres already one point by default

# assign the point coordinates to the spline points
for p, new_co in zip(spline.points, coords_list):
    p.co = (new_co + [1.0]) # (add nurbs weight)

# make a new object with the curve
obj = bpy.data.objects.new('object_name', crv)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj)
```

To add a point at the end it's simply:

```
spline = bpy.data.objects["object_name"].data.splines[0]
spline.points.add()
spline.points[-1].co = (1,1,5,1)
```

or to add more points at the end:

```
more_coords = [...list of more coords...]
spline.points.add(len(more_coords)
for p, new_co in zip(spline.points[-len(more_coords):]:
    p.co = new_co + [1] # if new_co is a list [x,y,z]
```

You can always get the coords of the points of the spline with

```
points_coords = [p.co for p in spline.points]
```

edit this list, i.g.

```
points_coords = points_coords[3:5] + [1.5,2,2.5,1] + points_coords[5:]
```

and then remove the spline or object and make a new one with the updated coordinates.

Comment: how to make this working for version 2.8?

Comment: Matthew posted an update below.

Answer (score 7):

An update for Blender 2.8

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj)
```

is now

```
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
```

and

```
spline.points.add()
```

needs to pass a number

```
spline.points.add(1)
```